# Is there any way to set aspect ratio for react-native Layout?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, aspect-ratio

I need to set a layout height 60% of its width. AbsoluteLayout/DockLayout/GridLayout/StackLayout/WrapLayout/FlexboxLayout any?

Any suggestion about how I can achieve this?

Comment: You will have to calculate it, `layoutChanged` event let you find the current width & height of layout then you may apply 60% of the original width as height.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for the quick response. I will try it out at my end. Appreciate if you can share sample code.

Comment: But problem is layoutChangedEvent does not fire on iOS Page https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7085

Comment: The issue is reported only on Page level not on layout level.

Comment: @Manoj When I try this on a RadListView item, in android it worked. But in iOS heigh not updated. Any idea?

Comment: This was not intended to use with list view, you can not adjust the height after it's rendered. Calculate the height once before setting data and bind the height on template.

Comment: @Manoj But height may be dynamic right? If we have an image view and few Labels then the height will be dynamic with respect to content.

Comment: Yes, but your image must have fixed size, so i assume you must be able to calculate it upfront. You can not update height of ListView item in iOS it's a limitations.

Comment: @Manoj Ok got it. Im new to this. Any clue how we can bind the height on template? I tried keeping a param on ViewModel but it didn't worked.

Comment: There is nothing specific to ListView template, it's just like any other view model binding. Share the playground sample if you have issues.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=y2ZAal&v=2
itemHeight="{{ itemHeight }} added in ListViewGridLayout and itemHeight defined in view model. It didnt work.  @Manoj

Comment: Looks like it's an [open issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1163), you will have to update it from code behind file.

Comment: @Manoj "update it from code behind file" Sorry, I didn't get that point. We can not change height of list item once it is loaded right?

Comment: Check the linked issue, you have all the details there. You can update the list view layout height upon loading the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for `layoutChanged` event, then measure the width and apply the calculated height.

**XML**

```
<GridLayout backgroundColor="red" layoutChanged="onLayoutChanged"></GridLayout>
```

**TS**

```
export function onLayoutChanged(args: EventData) {
    const gridLayout = <GridLayout>args.object,
        height = (layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(gridLayout.getMeasuredWidth()) / 100) * 60;

    gridLayout.off("layoutChanged");
    setTimeout(() => {
        gridLayout.height = height;
    });
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ciEqBu)

Comment: Worked! Thanks alote.